# Create complex SQL statement - CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to find if the user entered date overlaps any date on the database.

I've got the SQL statement down (might need a few tweaks, will test) but I'm struggling to get it into cakePHP correctly.

**What do I have**

```
$result = $this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'AND' => array(
                array('BoardroomBooking.start_time >=' => $this->data['BoardroomBooking']['start_time']),
                array('BoardroomBooking.start_time <' => $this->data['BoardroomBooking']['start_time'])
            ),
            'AND' => array(
                array('BoardroomBooking.start_time <=' => $this->data['BoardroomBooking']['start_time']),
                array('BoardroomBooking.start_time >' => $this->data['BoardroomBooking']['end_time'])
            )
        )
    )
));
```

**What does it create**

```
SQL Query: SELECT `BoardroomBooking`.`id`, `BoardroomBooking`.`name`,
`BoardroomBooking`.`boardroom_id`, `BoardroomBooking`.`date`, 
`BoardroomBooking`.`start_time`, `BoardroomBooking`.`end_time`, 
`BoardroomBooking`.`notes`, `BoardroomBooking`.`recurrence_id`, 
`BoardroomBooking`.`created`, `BoardroomBooking`.`modified`, `Boardroom`.`id`, 
`Boardroom`.`name`, `Boardroom`.`created`, `Boardroom`.`modified` FROM 
`intraweb_db`.`boardroom_bookings` AS `BoardroomBooking` LEFT JOIN 
`intraweb_db`.`boardrooms` AS `Boardroom` ON (`BoardroomBooking`.`boardroom_id`
 = `Boardroom`.`id`) WHERE ((`BoardroomBooking`.`start_time` <= '12:55:00') AND 
(`BoardroomBooking`.`start_time` > '13:00:00'))
```

**What I want**

```
SQL Query: SELECT `BoardroomBooking`.`id`, `BoardroomBooking`.`name`,
`BoardroomBooking`.`boardroom_id`, `BoardroomBooking`.`date`, 
`BoardroomBooking`.`start_time`, `BoardroomBooking`.`end_time`, 
`BoardroomBooking`.`notes`, `BoardroomBooking`.`recurrence_id`, 
`BoardroomBooking`.`created`, `BoardroomBooking`.`modified`, `Boardroom`.`id`, 
`Boardroom`.`name`, `Boardroom`.`created`, `Boardroom`.`modified` FROM 
`intraweb_db`.`boardroom_bookings` AS `BoardroomBooking` LEFT JOIN 
`intraweb_db`.`boardrooms` AS `Boardroom` ON (`BoardroomBooking`.`boardroom_id`
 = `Boardroom`.`id`) WHERE (`BoardroomBooking`.`start_time` >= '12:55:00' AND 
`BoardroomBooking`.`start_time` < '12:55:00') OR (`BoardroomBooking`.`start_time`
 <= '12:55:00') AND (`BoardroomBooking`.`start_time` > '13:00:00'))
```

I've read up on the documentation of how to [retrieve data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html), but for the life of me can't get it to work the way I want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I could be incorrect, but I believe your issue is within your array declaration:

```
  array(
    'AND' => array(
      ...
    ),
    'AND' => array(
      ...
    )
  )
```

As far as PHP is concerned you've just declared an "AND" key in the array, then re-assigned it. According to the [Cake Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions), you need to declare identical fields in separate arrays:

```
'OR' => array(
  array('AND' => array (...)),
  array('AND' => array (...))
)
```

This should prevent the query from treating your two conditions as the same thing and overwriting the entry.